# Ruby On Rails. converting integer into Business days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ROR and I am in need of some help.

In my def create_task, I'm trying to make to work this piece of code. It doesn't cause any errors in the browser, but it wouldn't work so far. In my view file I have a select tag which receives the start_date and another one for the due_date, which is optional. You also have to enter an integer, which corresponds to the number of days it's gonna take, which I have to convert into business days if the due_date is not selected already.
Do you have any idea of how could I make it work or do anybody see why the below mentioned code doesn't work? Thank you in advance

```
if @task.due_date.blank?
  @task.due_date = @tache.start_date
  while @i < @tache.charge
    @task.due_date = @task.due_date + 1.days
    if !@task.due_date.wday == 6 || !@task.due_date.wday == 0
      @i += 1         
    end
    @task.save         
  end
end
@task.save
```

Comment: Try to use `save!` instead of `save`, it will raise an exception if the object can't be saved (for example when validation fails).

Comment: Doesn't work. Thank you anyway

Comment: What is the start value of @i?

Comment: I've tried to initialize to zero, but that also doesn't work. Just forgot this line here. I'm just using it for the loop.

Comment: I've solved the problem by using a "for in" loop